# HTML, jQuery - Print values after updating form - input in arrays

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

i have table with input form with fields like this. Also I have function to add row, after click - below.

And my question is how to dynamically display sum of all values after change from for example Field1.

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Field 1</td>
      <td>Field 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="count[]" placeholder="Date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="field1[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="field2[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('table')" />
  </table>
```

Here is jQuery:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var $row = '<tr>'+
      '<td><input type="text" name="count[]" placeholder="Date"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="text" name="field1[]"></td>'+
      '<td><input type="text" name="field2[]"></td>'+
'</tr>'
if( rowCount <= 15)
  $('#table').append($row);
else {
  alert("Error.");
}
```

And i need to add something like this after the table:

```
<span>SUM_FROM_FIELD1</span>
```

Thank you, for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a changing event on some parent of `field1[]` and delegate it to them, to fire it any time any `field1[]` input changes, even if it's new.

A calling on array `reduce()` will help you a lot to sum the values (mind you it's for IE9+. For older browsers you have to sum the old way)

```
$("#table").on("change", "[name^=field1]", function() {
    var result = Array.reduce($("[name^=field1]"), function(carry, input) {
        return carry + parseInt($(input).val());
    }, 0);
    $(".sum_field_1").text(result);
}
```

Mind you that I suppose your SUM_FOR_FIELD1 span tag has a class called `.sum_field_1`

If possible, add to every `field1[]` input a class, so the selector would be easier, as selecting by name attribute is quite expensive.